# SharePoint stsadm addsolution - fails with permission based error (object ref)

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

Attempting to deploy a MOSS solution to a UAT server from dev server *for the first time*. On executing this command

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename xxx
```

I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
Based on these links: (and others):

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/63f0f95d-1215-4041-be6d-64ae63bda276/][1]

[http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/thread/b311D-bachea.aspx
I made sure of the following:][1]

1. I am a member of the farm admin group on the MOSS server
2. I am member of the WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG on the server
3. I was already in the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group on the server

I checked the event log and found exceptions saying that the login to my Site Services DB failed.

If I attempt to add myself via SQL Server Mgt Studio I do not have access to set access to that DB such as this:

> Reason: Cannot open database
>   "SharedServices1_DB" requested by the
>   login. The login failed.  Login failed
>   for user 'XXXXX\Administrator'.

So, what am I missing? Any obvious things I need to do? Any helpful suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

[1]: http://MSDN forum thread

[1]: http://Telerik support thread

Comment: I had this in my event logs: Event Type:Error; Event Source:Windows SharePoint Services 3; Event Category:Database; Event ID: 3760 -- SQL Database 'SharePoint_AdminContent_XXXXXXXXX' on SQL Server instance 'SqlServerName' not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. Cannot open database "SharePoint_AdminContent_XXXXXXX" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the obvious thing you are missing is that the user account doesn't have the required permission to use the sharepoint database - just as it says in your post ;)

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of defined by the question wasn't it? Funny how you can get so frustrated by a problem you can see the answer and still mmiss it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding solutions has nothing to do with the SSP.

Usually this error would be because the user executing the stsadm command does not have access to the farm configuration database. This has to do with the fact that only the "farm credentials" account has access to the farm configuration database.

You can try one of two things:

1. Run the stsadm command as the "farm credential" account. Usually this is a service account, by default it is that account that was used to create the farm database during the installation process.
2. Change the "farm credential" account to your logged in user. You can do this by using stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to not be with your solution, but with the SSP. Try deleting the UAT SSP and re-creating it and associate with your site(s).

If that works, you will need to find out why the issue occured.